# How to put 6 images in 3 columns-2 rows?

Tags: graphics, columns

i tried to put 6 images in a 3x2 imagebox using this code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_1.png}\quad
  \caption{image1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_2.png}\quad
  \caption{image2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}\quad
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_3.png}
  \caption{image3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_4.png}\quad
  \caption{image4}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_5.png}\quad
  \caption{image5}
  \label{fig:5}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_6.png}
  \caption{image6}
  \label{fig:6}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
\label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
```

I obtain the images as i wanted in 3 columns 2 rows, but the third one on the first row is shifted to the right, and i don't know how to fix it.

[image: 3x2 but not aligned]

thank for your help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One more suggestion:

- make figure content centered with use of `\centering`
- between sub figures insert `\hfil`
- purpose of `\quad` is not clear, let remove it
- centering of `subfigure` content is surplus. Rather make sub figure width smaller and adopt figure width to width of subfigure

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{image1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{image2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{image3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{image4}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{image5}
  \label{fig:5}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{image6}
  \label{fig:6}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
\label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need those \quads. Add a blank line between the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₁.png}
    \caption{image1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₂.png}
    \caption{image2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}\quad
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₃.png}
    \caption{image3}
    \label{fig:3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₄.png}
    \caption{image4}
    \label{fig:4}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₅.png}
    \caption{image5}
    \label{fig:5}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₆.png}
    \caption{image6}
    \label{fig:6}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
  \label{fig:images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You did \quad before the the third \includegraphics moving it behind it like in the other cases should fix it.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_1.png}\quad
  \caption{image1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_2.png}\quad
  \caption{image2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}%"\quad" not here since this will insert a spacing before the image.
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_3.png}\quad %but here
  \caption{image3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_4.png}\quad
  \caption{image4}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_5.png}\quad
  \caption{image5}
  \label{fig:5}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp_6.png}
  \caption{image6}
  \label{fig:6}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
\label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please extend your answer to show the corrected code.  Such one-liners are discouraged on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfigure[image1]{\fbox{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{~}}}}\quad
\subfigure[image2]{\fbox{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{~}}}}\quad
\subfigure[image3]{\fbox{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{~}}}}\quad\\
\subfigure[image4]{\fbox{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{~}}}}\quad
\subfigure[image5]{\fbox{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{~}}}}\quad
\subfigure[image6]{\fbox{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{~}}}}\quad
\caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
\label{fig:images}
\end{figure}        
\end{document}
```

Replace `\fbox{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{~}}}` with `\includegraphics{...}`. If you need 3x2 then give `\\` after second `\subfigure`. Now it is 2x3.