# How to make 8 subfigures fit in one page?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am a newbie in Latex and I have 8 figures with equal sizes to plot. I want to arrange them in 4*2 and plot them in one page.

```
 \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots1.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots2.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots3.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots4.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
     \\
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots5.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots6.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
     \\
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots7.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plots8.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{blah blah blah blah ...}
\end{figure}
```

I want to do these:

1. Reduce the horizontal distance between two subfigures to have equal distances between them and the edge of the page.
2. Reduce the vertical distance between two subfigures so I may be able to increase the size of each of them. (The reason why I chose 0.32\textwidth is because I wanted to fit them all in one page. Do you have better idea to increase their width and height? They don't need to keep the ratio between width and height of the original images)
3. Add subcaptions on the top-left (or left) of each image as a,b,c,d,...

I would really appreciate it if you can help me.
Thanks a lot.
Ali

Comment: Please provide a [minimally working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/16782), that includes a documentclass, etc. Something that someone can copy and compile without adding anything :)

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about the natural sizes of the images. E.g, in their natural size, are they about square, more tall than wide, or less tall than wide?

Comment: see, if answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316435/how-to-put-6-images-in-3-columns-2-rows/316444#316444 can help you.

Comment: Your stated objective, "Reduce the vertical distance between two subfigures", is a bit puzzling as there is virtually no (vertical) separation in your code at present. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your comment. my problem is solved. I used the below codes with some \vspace and \hspace.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you looking for something like this:

[image]

For this figure I use `subfig` and `floatrow` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:a}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:b}}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:c}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:d}}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:e}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:f}}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:g}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:h}}
\caption{Main caption \dots}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much. This is exactly what I wanted. 
I have two quick questions:

Do you know if there is a way to have labels as (a), (b),...  than a,b, in this setting?

How can I change width and height simultaneously. I don't need to have the same ratio as the original picture.

Thanks again

Comment: Form of labels is determined by labelformat=..... I select option`simple` (which is default), if you select `parens` you should gives what you looking for. Nex question I don't understand well. If your images are different size and like to show them in the same size, then >(as far as i know) is not such (direct) possibilities