# how to position subfigure labels

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I want the subfigures labels/numbers to appear on left of them instead of bottom. For example, in the following[image]

I want to have the labels a, b and c appear on left of the figures instead of bottom. The code taken from [How to create subfloat figures (two in first row and one below)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64858/how-to-create-subfloat-figures-two-in-first-row-and-one-below) is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:a}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:b}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:c}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-c}}

\caption{my fig}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I place the labels on left of the subfigures?

Comment: related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

adopted from answer [sidesubfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/sidesubfloats-why-does-this-errored-code-work-and-my-correct-code-doesnt) of  [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) and my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317295/how-to-make-8-subfigures-fit-in-one-page/317323#317323):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\label{main:a}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\label{main:b}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

\bigskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\label{main:c}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{My figure with side subcaptions}
\label{fig:main}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Follow up question - if I include the packages you have included, for a different figure in the document created by '\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
  \caption{fig2 }
  \label{fig2}
\end{figure}' , I get the error 'You can't use `\vadjust' in vertical mode'. Do you know why?

Comment: sorry, from this fragments i cant figured from where is mentioned problem. please, ask new question and in it provide *mwe* which demonstrate it. maybe you have some packages cash or something else ... with code fragment in your comment added to my *mwe* i can't reproduce mentioned error.

Comment: Let me first try to explain here. 2 questions. How can I have paranthesis around a, b and c? And how do I include a separate single figure (only one subfigure) w/o any labels a, b or c using the sidesubfloat command?

Comment: @user25957, you need to set up caption accordingly. please read `subfig` documentation (as I should do to answer on your new questions in comment) . there i found on page 29 that default style is `parens`. this means, you should remove option `labelformat=simple`.

Comment: can I do the same without floatrow? floatrow gives me errors for other figures. For example, the one that I have mentioned before. I don't know why the error is coming and hence, I was unable to prepare the MWE.

Comment: and here's the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389646/using-floatrow-gives-vadjust-errors-in-figure