# How to place six subfigures in 2 columns x 3 rows form, where column first shall be considered instead of row first

Tags: floats, minipage

I have been struggling to place 6 subfigures in 2 columns and 3 rows, where the subfigures should be stacked in column first (one main caption) -- see illustration below.

In the following question, the subfigures are stacked in row first (but I want column first): [How to put 6 images in 3 columns-2 rows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316435/how-to-put-6-images-in-3-columns-2-rows?rq=1)

Can someone please help me? Thank you

---

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For suchh a layout, you can ude tow minipages with the optional argument [t] for the vertical alignment of the minipages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the code at the cited anser, I set 3 images vertically in one minipage, and then set the next three vertically in the next minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering % <-- added
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{image1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{image2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{image3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{image4}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{image5}
  \label{fig:5}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{image6}
  \label{fig:6}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
\label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]