# Pgf-pie in subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, pgf-pie

I have the following code that draw four pie-chart using `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\definecolor{Azul}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfigure[Solution 1]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,text=legend,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{49.9/Ideal month,
18.2/One month,
9/Two months,
22.9/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\subfigure[Solution 2]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,text=legend,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{16.2/Ideal month,
31/One month,
20/Two months,
32.8/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\subfigure[Solution 3]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,text=legend,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{12.2/Ideal month,
18.7/One month,
20.6/Two months,
48.5/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\subfigure[Solution 4]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,text=legend,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{29.9/Ideal month,
17.2/One month,
19.3/Two months,
33.6/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\caption{Proportions of the total area harvested with different deviations (in module) from the ideal period}
\label{Proportion_time}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

whose result is the following:

[image]

There is a way to draw only one legend for the four graphics, avoiding to be redundant? But, I would like to maintain the environment `subfigure` to differ one chart from other (because the different captions...).
Many thanks.

Comment: Sooner or later you are going to have to stop using the subfigure package.  \subfloat behaves the same and is supported both by subfig and subcaption.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Is there a better post I can reference in my post that shows an example based on the packages you suggested? You can edit my post directly if you know something.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the legend yourself. Here is an example where the legend is placed at the top of the pie charts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\definecolor{Azul}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering

% create legend
% based on the code of the pgf-pie package
% https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/blob/master/tex/latex/pgf-pie/tikzlibrarypie.code.tex#L481-L492
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (legendpos) at (0,0);
    \begin{scope}[node distance=2.5cm]
        \foreach \labelName/\color in {Ideal month/Azul!70, One month/orange!70, Two months/red!70, Three months/yellow!70} {
            \node[draw, fill={\color}, right of={legendpos}, label={0:{\labelName}}] (legendpos) {};
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

% code to create the pie charts with a caption
% copy and paste from the question
\subfigure[Solution 1]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,% <- removed text=legend
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{49.9/Ideal month,
18.2/One month,
9/Two months,
22.9/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\subfigure[Solution 2]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,% <- removed text=legend
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{16.2/Ideal month,
31/One month,
20/Two months,
32.8/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\subfigure[Solution 3]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,% <- removed text=legend
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{12.2/Ideal month,
18.7/One month,
20.6/Two months,
48.5/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\subfigure[Solution 4]{
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=3,% <- removed text=legend
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{29.9/Ideal month,
17.2/One month,
19.3/Two months,
33.6/Three months}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\caption{Proportions of the total area harvested with different deviations (in module) from the ideal period}
\label{Proportion_time}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please also take a look at this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316444/269505), because your code for arranging your pie charts is not the best.

Comment: Where can I insert the caption: (a) solution 1, (b) solution 2, etc... below of each pie-chart?

Comment: @AngeloAlianoFilho: You can use the same code as the one in your question and maybe tweak it based on my reference or John Kormylo's comment. Only add the `tikzpicture` environment before.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to use `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure`.  Also, getting rid of the text is slightly more difficult than removing `[text=legend]`.  Finally, pgf-pie adds extra space in an irregular manner, as shown by the red rectangles (which can and should be removed).  I used `\pgfresetboundingbox` to remove this extra space and  `\path` to replace it with a new bounding box.

I also stole the legend from the unknown benefactor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\definecolor{Azul}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}}
% based on the code of the pgf-pie package
% https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/blob/master/tex/latex/pgf-pie/tikzlibrarypie.code.tex#L481-L492
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (legendpos) at (0,0);
    \begin{scope}[node distance=2.5cm]
        \foreach \labelName/\color in {Ideal month/Azul!70, One month/orange!70, Two months/red!70, Three months/yellow!70} {
            \node[draw, fill={\color}, right of={legendpos}, label={0:{\labelName}}] (legendpos) {};
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\subfloat[Solution 1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\pie[radius=3,text=inside,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{49.9/,
18.2/,
9/,
22.9/}
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path (3,3) (-3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\hfil
\subfloat[Solution 2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\pie[radius=3,text=inside,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{16.2/,
31/,
20/,
32.8/}
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path (3,3) (-3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\hfil
\subfloat[Solution 3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\pie[radius=3,text=inside,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{12.2/,
18.7/,
20.6/,
48.5/}
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path (3,3) (-3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\hfil
\subfloat[Solution 4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\pie[radius=3,text=inside,
color={Azul!70,orange!70,red!70,yellow!70}]
{29.9/,
17.2/,
19.3/,
33.6/}
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path (3,3) (-3,-3);

\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\caption{Proportions of the total area harvested with different deviations (in module) from the ideal period}
\label{Proportion_time}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]