# Figure placement with difference column distances

Tags: graphics, subcaption, columns

I want to do subfigures with two main columns and 5 rows. Each column itself, would break down into 3 sub-columns (in total it would be `2*3=6` columns and `6*5=30` images). I want to have a caption for each column and each figure as well. Also, **I want the two main column distance be more than the sub-columns** so it would show that they are referring to two different categories. I'm able to get everything except the distance between two main columns using [How to put 6 images in 3 columns-2 rows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316435/how-to-put-6-images-in-3-columns-2-rows).

I tried using two `subfigures` (one inside the other) but it didn't work. Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, edited it. @Mico

Comment: How should the subcaptions be numbered? 1 thru 30? `n.1` thru `n.30`, where "n" would be the main caption's number?

Comment: Can they not be numbered? just be plain caption. @Mico

Answer (score 2):

The following solution places 15 `subfigure` environments into two `minipage` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,showframe} % don't load 'showframe' in real doc.

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p!]
% widths and heights of graphs
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=0.145\textheight} 

\caption*{A figure with 30 subfigures}

\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{aa}
  \caption*{aa}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ab}
  \caption*{ab}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ac}
  \caption*{ac}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ad}
  \caption*{ad}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ae}
  \caption*{ae}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{af}
  \caption*{af}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ag}
  \caption*{ag}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ah}
  \caption*{ah}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ai}
  \caption*{ai}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{aj}
  \caption*{aj}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ak}
  \caption*{ak}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{al}
  \caption*{al}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{am}
  \caption*{am}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{an}
  \caption*{an}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ao}
  \caption*{ao}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{ba}
  \caption*{ba}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bb}
  \caption*{bb}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bc}
  \caption*{bc}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bd}
  \caption*{bd}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{be}
  \caption*{be}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bf}
  \caption*{bf}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bg}
  \caption*{bg}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bh}
  \caption*{bh}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bi}
  \caption*{bi}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bj}
  \caption*{bj}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bk}
  \caption*{bk}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bl}
  \caption*{bl}
  \end{subfigure}

\medskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bm}
  \caption*{bm}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bn}
  \caption*{bn}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
  \includegraphics{bo}
  \caption*{bo}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question about how to place a row of captions across the six columns of `subfigure` environments. One way I can think of doing this is to create a row of `minipage` environments after the main `\caption` directive, with widths given by the subsequent `subfigure` environments, and then place a `\caption*` directive inside each `minipage`. I.e., something like this:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.1536\textwidth}% 0.48*0.32=0.1536
   \caption*{aaaa}
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.0096\textwidth}% 0.0096=(0.48-3*0.1536)/2
\begin{minipage}{0.1536\textwidth}
   \caption*{bbbb}
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.0096\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{0.1536\textwidth}
   \caption*{cccc}
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}% 0.04=1-2*0.48
\begin{minipage}{0.1536\textwidth}
   \caption*{dddd}
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.0096\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{0.1536\textwidth}
   \caption*{eeee}
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.0096\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{0.1536\textwidth}
   \caption*{ffff}
\end{minipage}
```

You may need to adjust the directive

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=0.145\textheight}
```

to

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=0.14\textheight}
```

since the new row of captions takes up some space, leaving less (vertical) space for the graphs.

Comment: Thank you tons Mico! Can I also add a caption for each of columns (6 caption in total)?

Comment: @statwoman - Please see the addendum I posted.